# How to optimize a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a problem with a mysql query that sometimes needs more than 80 secs to execute.

Could you please help me to optimize it?

Here my sql code

```
SELECT
 codFinAtl,
 nome,
 cognome,
 dataNascita AS annoNascita,
 MIN(tempoRisultato) AS tempoRisultato
FROM
graduatorie
INNER JOIN anagrafica ON codFin = codFinAtl
INNER JOIN manifestazionigrad ON manifestazionigrad.codice = graduatorie.codMan
WHERE
 anagrafica.eliminato = 'n' 
 AND graduatorie.eliminato = 'n' 
 AND codGara IN('01', '81') 
 AND sesso = 'F' 
 AND manifestazionigrad.aa = '2018/19' 
 AND graduatorie.baseVasca = '25' 
 AND tempoRisultato IS NOT NULL 
 AND dataNascita BETWEEN '20050101' AND '20061231'
GROUP BY
 codFinAtl
ORDER BY
 tempoRisultato,
 cognome,
 nome
```

And my db schema
[image]

[UPDATE]

Here there is the results of EXPLAIN query

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type   | possible_keys            | key       | key_len | ref                           | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | anagrafica         | NULL       | ALL    | codFin                   | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                          | 334094 |     0.11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | graduatorie        | NULL       | ref    | codMan,codFinAtl,codGara | codFinAtl | 33      | finsicilia.anagrafica.codFin  |     20 |     0.24 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | manifestazionigrad | NULL       | eq_ref | codice                   | codice    | 32      | finsicilia.graduatorie.codMan |      1 |    10.00 | Using index condition; Using where           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: In addition, questions about query optimisation always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: And how come 'manifestazionigrad.codice' gets qualified, and nothing else? :-( ?

Comment: We need to see the indexes; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The query is clumsy to read since some columns are not qualified by the table they are in.  Have you heard of "composite indexes"?

Comment: @Strawberry I added the EXPLAIN results

Comment: Thanks for the progress report

Answer (score 0):

```
graduatorie:  INDEX(eliminato, baseVasca)
manifestazionigrad:  INDEX(aa, codMan)
```

These may not be sufficient.  Please qualify each column in the query so we know which table they come from.

But the real problem is probably "explode-implode".  First it explodes by `JOINing`, then it implodes by `GROUP BY`.

Is it possible to compute `MIN(tempoRisultato)` *without* any `JOINs`?  (I can't even tell which table is involved.)  If so, provide that, then we can discuss what to do next.  There may be two choices:  a derived table with the `MIN`, or a subquery in the `JOIN` that may be correlated or uncorrelated.

(`tempoRisultato` seems to be in two tables!)